# Python/Json - Check for a specific object in multiple files

Tags: python, json, file, for-loop, if-statement

I have a huge amount of json files (4000) and I need to check every single one of them for a specific object. My code is like the following:

```
import os
import json

files = sorted(os.listdir("my files path"))
for f in files:
    if f.endswith(".json"): 
        myFile = open("my path\\" + f)
        myJson = json.load(bayesFile)
        if myJson["something"]["something"]["what im looking for"] == "ACTION"
            #do stuff
        myFile.close()
```

As you can imagine this is taking a lot of execution time and I was wondering if there is a quicker way...?

Comment: Have you considered multithreading or multiprocessing if you '#do Stuff' code is CPU intensive? Also, your code as shown isn't runnable

Comment: Tbh I never used multithreading or multiprocessing in python so it didn't cross my mind. The #doStuff is not intensive, just a few operations, it's just a very long <<open file, check file, close file>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a multithreaded approach that may help you:

```
from glob import glob
import json
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import os

BASEDIR = 'myDirectory' # the directory containing the json files

def process(filename):
    with open(filename) as infile:
        data = json.load(infile)
        if data.get('foo', '') == 'ACTION':
            pass # do stuff

def main():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(process, glob(os.path.join(BASEDIR, '*.json')))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```